# Instantiating a COM and ATL type

Tags: c++, com, c++-cli, atl

I have never used either COM or ATL before but now I'm faced with code which uses both. The call to CreateInstance in the code below returns a HRESULT which is not recognised by _com_error.ErrorMessage, i.e. the error string is "unknown error: 0x8876086c". I'm a little confused about what function is actually being called though, as the IClassFactory interface just declares a pure virtual function CreateInstance, and the type of _AtlComModule, 'CAtlComModule', doesn't seem to have a CreateInstance member function.

```
STDMETHODIMP CGdtvEngine::CoCreateInstance(const CLSID &clsid, const IID &iid, void **obj)
{
    CComPtr <IClassFactory> factory;
    HRESULT hr = AtlComModuleGetClassObject(&_AtlComModule, clsid, __uuidof(factory), (void **)&factory);
    _com_error err1(hr);
    Log(_T("Result of AtlComModuleGetClassObject: %s"), err1.ErrorMessage();
    hr = factory->CreateInstance(NULL, iid, obj);
    _com_error err2(hr);
    Log(_T("Result of factory->CreateInstance: %s"), err2.ErrorMessage() );
    return hr;
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT - I should add, as I don't have the ability to remote debug this I can't just step into the function using the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x8876086c` is `D3DERR_INVALIDCALL` so the underlying cause of the problem is likely to be something related to Direct3D, not COM or ATL. To troubleshoot this further, you need to look at CLSID and IID arguments you are using there, in order to see what exactly COM object is failing with this code.